# How to check which string value are null or empty in all string android?

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio

I know that how to check string value is null or empty?. But here I have some other type of problem so please read full question.
Now, I have total 16 string in my code

```
        String name = sharedPreferences.getString("name", "");
        String email = sharedPreferences.getString("email", "");
        String mobile = sharedPreferences.getString("mobile", "");
        String gender = sharedPreferences.getString("gender", "");
        String roll_no = sharedPreferences.getString("roll_no", "");
        String er_no = sharedPreferences.getString("enr_no", "");
        String address = sharedPreferences.getString("address", "");
        String state = sharedPreferences.getString("state", "");
        String city = sharedPreferences.getString("city", "");
        String pincode = sharedPreferences.getString("pincode", "");
        String alt_mobile = sharedPreferences.getString("alt_mobile", "");
        String program = sharedPreferences.getString("program", "");
        String image = sharedPreferences.getString("image","");
        String dob = sharedPreferences.getString("dob","");
        String course = sharedPreferences.getString("course", "");
        String year = sharedPreferences.getString("year", "");
        String sem = sharedPreferences.getString("sem","");
        String fname = sharedPreferences.getString("fname","");
```

and set all value in related textview.

```
       textViewName.setText(name);
       textViewFname.setText(fname);
       textViewEmail.setText(email);
       textViewmobile.setText(mobile);
       textViewGender.setText(gender);
       textViewdob.setText(dob);
       textViewcourse.setText(course);
       textViewYear.setText(year);
       textViewSem.setText(sem);
       textViewErno.setText(er_no);
       textViewAdd.setText(address);
       textViewRollNo.setText(roll_no);
       textViewRemainAdd.setText(city + ", " + state + ", " + pincode);
       textViewAltMob.setText(alt_mobile);
       textViewPrograme.setText(program);
```

and I do not want to check all string one by one like..

```
 if (Objects.requireNonNull(roll_no).equals("")){
        textViewRollNo.setText("Null Value");
    }else {
        textViewRollNo.setText(roll_no);
    }
```

Can I check all string in one loop or if any string is null then I can print **"Null Value"** message in related `textview`.
I do not know that I am asking write question but if any way to do it so please share a code to solve this problem.

Comment: Why not wrap that check in a function that takes a `TextView` as an argument?

Comment: I don know why someone devoted my question with out any particular reason . if someone think this is easy so may be its easy for that but i have a problem so i asked here.

Comment: @Neijwiert I do not know how to do that can give me some code.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could make the "default value" be "Null Value", unless you suspect that the string you saved to the sharedPreferences might have been an empty string?

```
String state = sharedPreferences.getString("state", "Null Value");
```

Otherwise, you will have to make a method maybe:

```
public String getCorrectValue(String value) {
    return value.isEmpty()? "Null Value" : value; 
}
```

Comment: Ya, Making `default_value` in getString() itself as the string "Null value" instead of "" should be totally sufficient. Checking wont be required at all.

Comment: @Zee how can i do for all string without redundant code according to your other method

Comment: Well, it would have to look something like this:
 textViewAdd.setText(getCorrectValue (address));

Or like Neijwiert suggested. I don't think there is another way really.

Comment: @zee I cannot apply first method because server gives me a value as " " after that i am storing a value in sharedpreference so how can i solve this with your first method.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally pressed enter before my comment was done. Edited it.

Answer (score 0):

in Kotlin, it should be like this:

```
val myMap = mapOf (
  "name" to textViewName,
  "email" to textViewEmail,
  ... )
for ((key, view) in myMap) {
  val value = sp.getString(key, "")
  view.text = if (value.isEmpty()) "Null value" else value
}
```